# Phonegap and MobileIron compatibility

Tags: ios, cordova, mdm, nsurlprotocol

I developed a PhoneGap application for iOS devices. For security reasons, I need to integrate a MobileIron product. In particular, I have to import MobileIron's AppConnectSDK for iOS into my Xcode project. I'm concerned that`NSURLProtocol` subclass is instantiated twice. The first one by Phonegap (CDVURLProtocol) and the second one by AppConnectSDK.

Can these two instances work together? Is MobileIron's AppConnect compatible with PhoneGap?

Thanks,
Enri

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the MobileIron AppConnect SDK is fully compatible with PhoneGap.  If you contact us, we'll also share with you a PhoneGap plugin that allows you to interact with the SDK from the Javascript layer.

Comment: Does it support React-Native? i.e. Can I use IOS sdk on React-native, and then use a API from javascript?